# jQuery append img element with url on src not working in IE and FF

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an image tag that retrieves the src by an url, like:

`<img src="http://localhost:2000/User/GetImage/1" />`

That element is generated by jQuery, that is:

```
this.updateImage  = function() 
{
    console.log("Change me!");
    var context = this;
    var imageSrc = webApiUrl + "User/GetImage/" + this._id;

    $("#ga-application-header .user-info-image").each(function()
    {
        $(this).empty();
        /* First try */$(this).append($("<img title='" + context._firstName + " " + context._lastName + "' />").attr("src", imageSrc));
        /* Second try*/$(this).append("<img title='" + context._firstName + " " + context._lastName + "' src='" + imageSrc + "' />");
    });
}
```

That lines with coments - first and second try - are the way I've tried the get this achieved.

Now the most important detail. When page is loaded, this function is called and displays the image. This works. But if I call it again(when user change it's picture) the image doesn't shows in IE and FF. Only on Chrome. IE and FF don't even open an image request(on network tab in console) for it. Note that the `console.log` text "Change Me!" is always called.

Comment: It doesn't show any errors or anything? Anywhere?

Comment: check if the context in both the calls is the same.

Comment: @ParthikGosar I would say yes. The object, **User** is unique and global. The calls are always in it.

Comment: I wonder if this is a caching issue? What if you append a random query string to the end of the image src url?

Comment: Just making sure as calling the same function as a event handler changes its context. Could you create a jsfiddle for this...would be more convenient to help out.

Comment: Have you logged all the values to ensure they are identical in the different browsers?

Comment: If this is being called as a callback function for some event, the `this` variable may not be what you expect it to be.

Comment: @RandomWebGuy you're right. I just added `"&" + Math.random();` and all worked. Post an answer with it and I will accept. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is caused by the browser caching the image. The fix is to append a random query string to the image source.

Comment: Good job figuring this out. I would never have guessed!

Comment: This passed through my mind but I have no ideia how to avoid the cache.

Answer (score 3):

First, I tend to use the following pattern as opposed to string concatenation.

```
var img = $('<img/>').attr('title',context._firstName).attr('src',imageSrc);
$(this).append(img);
```

Second, inside your this.updateImage, could you console.log/dir(this), I'm guessing your context isn't proper, you may want to do a var that = this, to keep your references in check.

Comment: there's a quote which is not closed on `imageSrc` fix it please!

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the same issue with IE.

This helped me:

Instead of

```
$form.find( ".classname" ).append( content );
```

This worked in IE and all other browsers:

```
$form.find( ".classname" ).html( $form.find( ".classname" ).html() + content );
```

Hope it helps somebody here...